# Taskkill harming things or not?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I know that ALT+F4 can close a program. I know that Task manager can close a program and I am aware that taskkill can close a program. What I am curious about is if you close programs/games/applications or whatever it might be with the mentioned methods will it do any harm to your hardware or os? I know taskkill can force close things as well. Task manager can as well if I remember right but alt+f4 sends a request to close right?

Basically I am curious if using taskkill to close things with either taskkill /f /t /im OR taskkill /im can cause harm to your hardware or os? If say a game is in the middle of saving when it happens I am aware that it can corrupt things but if not done during a save would it be safe to use taskkill to close things instead of going through menus, or hitting the red x? I have a few buttons on the side that I can press to close things without having to click into them or interact with them cause it is all set up with batch files and such but was wondering if that could have any bad outcomes.

Comment: If you force quit a program while it is writing data, you have data corruption. Often this isn't very important.  If you force quit a game while it is saving your save game you may have a corrupted save game and you'll have to go back to the previous save game. Not a big deal. But if you are halfway upgrading your BIOS and you pull the plug you may have a real problem. Windows has DISM and SFC and CHKDSK to find, fix and repair missing or corrupted files.

Comment: [DISM](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image), [SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e), [chkdsk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer) and [what happens if you interrupt a BIOS update](https://youtu.be/dXbxDXj-7hA?t=359)

Comment: It is often safe to shut down a program by force quitting it, but the problem is that you usually do not know *when which program*  is writing data that will be corrupted if you force quit. A program like Notepad will only save data when you tell it to, but other programs (including Windows programs) continuously load and write all kinds of data. And a normal Windows pc often has a lot of programs running at the same time. So while its often not much of a problem if it happens once or twice, you shouldn't make an habit out of it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/541747/what-happens-when-bios-update-is-interrupted-not-completed

Comment: I am aware of SFC and CHKDSK I am less familiar with DISM? As in what it does but I have seen the acronym used before. But I don't understand how taskkill would mess with anything BIOS related atleast in the way I am using it. I use it to close chome or games or notepad from time to time or maybe MMC. But that doesn't stop those services as far as I am aware just closes the management console. But so far what I have gathered is that I should use taskkill /im, taskkill /im /t and not taskkill /im /t /f unless necessary if something isn't closing. I was aware you could corrupt saves if forced.

Comment: @Godsend - DISM only repairs system files, any task you can kill, isn’t associated with a system file. You don’t provide any specifics on which processes your interested in killing, by abruptly ending

Comment: Just games mainly or certain other things. Notepad, ICUE, Voice Attack, Chrome, DIscord, warframe. HWinfo64, MSI Afterburner if being weird to restart it. Streamdeck, GoXLR program if being weird basically instead of click the red x I make a .bat file to close things with a press of a button instead of having to navigate to stuff to close it.

Comment: @ramhound sorry didn't tag you but I replied to you post about this one if it shows up right for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harm to the hardware by `taskkill` seem very improbable to me.

Harm to Windows is only possible if you use it to kill a Windows component
that works in cooperation with other components, but you need to be
really unlucky. Normally, killing a Windows component will only cause
the tasks that it does to become unavailable. Killing a vital process
will usually cause Windows to immediately reboot.

There is a big difference when using the `/f` switch or not. Using the
switch will cause the immediate termination of the process (unless
it's stuck in a kernel call that can't be terminated forcefully).

Without `/f`, taskkill will politely send the task a message that it
needs to terminate, same as clicking the X on the title bar.
Normally this should be tried first, since the
task will then shutdown in an orderly manner and without data loss.
Only if this fails should `/f` be used.

Comment: Oof I remember stopping a Windows Update (back in the day) and having to spend a week trying to fix the damage caused, failing, and having to reinstall the entire OS. On modern Windows this is easy to fix tho.

Comment: @Gantendo: This was before Windows 10, I suppose?

Comment: The bad old days, many years ago

Answer (score 0):

Both `taskkill` ([WM_CLOSE signal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close)) and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, also any other ways to interrupt and close processes can cause harm either to your software or system.

It all depends on how the closed process handles interruption. One app could handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> not fully properly and e.g. result in its config not saved correctly. I'd say that's rare nowadays with all the frameworks in use and what not, but it happened to me in the past, e.g. with the example you also provided - a game starting to save right after I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, which I guess it registered after the fact. Save file got corrupted.

And of course `taskkill /f` ([TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)) can cause more harm than the other alternatives as it skips some implemented security measures. Especially low level, e.g. system-related, processes could cause a lot of issues when forced to close.

I don't think this question is answerable in a general manner. I would just advise **not to use** `taskkill` in scripts **unless you're sure it's safe** - e.g. it can't damage any data or anything alike. Regular CLI/GUI apps that don't do I/O operations are the safest. Anything else - you might expect problems.

**TLDR summary**: it depends on the application/process, you should ensure nothing can go wrong, but it's likely to be safe most of the time nowadays.

Comment: the reason I used taskkill in the first place it is allows me to push something on my stream deck or voice attack to close a program or something running that I don't want to run but while doing other things so I don't wanna unfocus what I am doing to click the big red X or click it to focus to alt+F4 it closed. Taskkill lets me close chrome or other things while still doing what I am doing. I am not closing windows services as far as I know. I do use taskkill to close MMC when I do task scheduler stuff. I am not taskkill /im Svchost.exe just things like chrome or games.

Comment: Also how would taskkill harm hardware or software? Software I kinda get cause you end say a windows process and your pc BSOD or just becomes unresponsive and such. But you would need to end a windows process for that no? Not stuff like chrome, voice attack, discord, etc?

Comment: I haven't mentioned hardware anywhere, not sure what you're referring to. For software I wrote how - if it's not fully correctly handling that scenario. I also wrote it's unlikely with modern software if it's well-programmed. E.g. DIscord is very unlikely to have issues even if you force kill and even if it does, you're not going to lose almost anything as it's mostly web-based. Chrome could be more problematic as it saves data to various local databases etc., but non-forced kill is also unlikely to do anything bad as it's a commonly used actively developed software.

Comment: "harm either to your software or system." is system not referring to hardware? Software would be the OS or games and applications?
So then are you saying that taskkill /im is safe more or less as long as I don't use the /f force part of it? I am looking into powershell to as that seems to have a nicer way to ask things to shutdown while also letting it force a termination if it takes past a certain time. I just want a way to close things without haven't to have it in focus via a .bat or .ps1 but wanna make sure it doesn't harm anything.

Comment: No. System layer is between hardware and software layers and connects them. Simply system (OS), no hidden meaning. Yes, without `/f` it's safer for many types of applications, but you also will get traditional "Are you sure you want to close?" type of popups, which I'm not sure you want in your automation. Not sure if anything in PowerShell helps much here but doing in PS rather than batch should be preferred anyways. AHK could be easier for popup scenarios: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinClose.htm with combination of autoclicking "Yes" or similar buttons on appearing popups after.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah I can run the powershell stuff from the popup but am having trouble running it from the .ps1 itself like I could the .bat files.